# Redirect output from command to terminal and a file without using tee

Tags: linux, unix

As the name implies, I want to log the output of a command to a file without changing the terminal behavior. I still want to see the output and importantly, I still need to be able to do input.

The input requirement is why I specifically cannot use tee. The application I am working with doesn't handle input properly when using tee. (No, I cannot modify the application to fix this). I'm hoping a more fundamental approach with '>' redirection gets around this issue.

Theoretically, this should work exactly as I want, but, like I said, it does not.

```
command | tee -a foo.log
```

Also notice I added the -a flag. Not strictly required because I can definitely do a work around but it'd be nice if that was a feature as well.

Comment: what command are you exactly trying to run? it's important to know how it sends it's output to `stdout`.

Comment: Its a python file. I think it primarily uses the logging module but there might be a few print statements

Comment: None of these ideas solved the exact issue. I am not sure what specifically causes these to not function as I would need. I consulted reddit as well and got several other ideas. Same result. For now I've decided to just ignore this goal. Its not important enough for me to commit any more time to

Answer (score 0):

Use `script`.

```
% script -c vi vi.log
Script started, output log file is 'vi.log'.
... inside vi command - fully interactive - save the file, takes to:
Script done.
% ls -l vi.log
-rw-r--r-- 1 risner risner 889 Sep 13 15:16 vi.log
```